# Why disconnect a TCP socket in order to connect?

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp

I'm working on a piece of code, where a connection is made to a TCP socket.

The code contains the following excerpt:

```
// Close the socket if it is still open
if (_socket != null)
{
    Disconnect();
}

// Create the socket object
_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
```

The `DisConnect()` method does (amongst other things):

```
var socket = _socket;
_socket = null;
socket.Close();
```

I don't understand the beginning: why disconnect in order to connect?

I have tried removing that part of the code, but then the whole thing became very unstable.

Does anybody have an idea?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe it just want to establish a brand new connection like an http request.

Comment: @shingo: No, this always happens, http is not in the picture here (no need for modifying an existing connection at first sight).

Comment: What does the `Disconnect()` method actually do? We don't see it. And what does "unstable" mean in your particular case?

Comment: @Fildor: I've adapted my question. By unstable I mean that the socket sometimes can't be reopened, once it get closed.

Comment: Should not the question be why you are reconnecting? If you are recreating the socket the old one should obviously be closed/disconnected/disposed first. But without more info it is difficult to know it is reconnecting in the first place. Maybe there are no heartbeats keeping the socket open? I try to use higher level protocols to avoid these kinds of problems.

Comment: `_socket = null;
_socket.Close();` - No it doesn't. That would throw a NRE every time. That also means (if your program _does in fact run_) that the condition is never true and `Disconnect` is never called. Or you do in fact encounter an NRE, which would be caused by exactly that code.

Comment: @Fildor: sorry. I wanted to simplify but I went too far. I've corrected my question, avoiding the NullReferenceException.

Comment: Seems like a "graceful" shutdown of the "old" connection. What problems do you see reconnecting? Exceptions? Timeouts?

Comment: @Dominique I said "like". I mean this is just like when you refresh a loading page in the browser, the program need close the existing connection and then start a new one. So this is very normal.

Comment: If there's already a connection then stop that connection and start a new one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once a TCP socket has been closed, it can't be reused, so a new socket is needed for a new TCP connection.

If you want to reuse the same socket for a new TCP connection after a disconnect, you need to use the [`Socket.Disconnect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.disconnect?view=net-6.0) method with the `reuseSocket` parameter set to `true`.